# Calc. 2 shell method for $y = x^{3/2}$ for $y = 8$ and $x = 0$

Tags: calculus

[image]Using the equation $$2\pi\int_a^b(R)(H)dx$$ I get $$2\pi\int_0^4(x)(x)^{3/2} dx = 2\pi\int_0^4x^{5/2} dx = 2\pi\left[\frac{2}{7}x^{7/2}\right]_0^4 = \frac{512\pi}{7}$$ Where am I going wrong?

Comment: H is the distance from the curve $y = x^{\frac 32}$ to the line $y = 8$

Comment: The question really isn't clear. About what axis is this region being revolved?

Comment: Sorry. The y axis, and the $y = 8$ was just a limit. I did $8^\frac{2}{3} = 4$.

Comment: The line $y = 8$ is not just a limit.  Yes, you do use it to find one of your limits, but it is more than that.    It bounds the region.

Comment: I added a photo so you could see what I'm looking at. It says around the y-axis, so I just interpreted the $y = 8$ to mean I needed to solve for $x$. It normally would say revolve about $y = 8$

Answer (score 1):

It's
$$2\pi\int_0^4 x(8-x^{3/2}) dx$$

Comment: I see what you're saying now. It wants the region bounded by the two graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the volume of the region formed by the lines $y=0$, $x=4$ and $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ from the volume of a cylinder of radius $4$ and height $8$:

$$
V=\pi\cdot 4^2\cdot 8-2\pi\int_{0}^{4}x\cdot x^{\frac{3}{2}}\,dx=\frac{384\pi}{7}.
$$

[image]